# UTF-8 encoding issue of 2 columns in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, unicode, encoding, utf-8, xlsx

I have an Excel workbook that I need to edit but when I open it 2 of the columns have strange encoding (I think). Instead of normal values (strings) there are these strings:

```
¼àãëåíäðîáèëèöàêðàòêîáðîä
```

and

```
ÏÅËÈÑÒÅÐ-ÁÐÎÄ-ÄÐÎÁÈËÈÖÀ
```

I checked the document encoding (which is UTF-8), everything is written with Arial font, and there are no restrictions (I think) or hidden columns. I can edit all the columns but I need to get a normal value for these 2 columns to continue my work. I already tried saving the document with different encoding, tried Google Spreadsheet and tried changing language for non-Unicode programs in Control Panel but unfortunately nothing helped.

Is there a way to get their normal value?

Comment: This spread-sheet was probably created with a different font, one you don't have on your machine.  A non-Unicode font, not uncommon in India.  You'll need to know where the file came from.

Comment: I've tried putting local fonts but it doesn't change anything, I know the origin of the file so I also tried Cyrillic encode but it also didn't change anything. Also I think that if a font is missing there will be a warning when starting the file.

Comment: thank you pnuts, can you tell me how did you converted them in their normal form?

Answer (score 1):

Excel might be interpreting your textual data as `latin-1` or `windows-1252`, and not `UTF-8`. Is there an option for input encoding when you do an import?

I was able to fix formatting issues like this with Open Office's export/import functionality.

Comment: I think there is no option for input encoding, also the content of the columns I copied into notepad and there i started to change the encoding but it gave no result.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.